# Is it possible to dynamically change/remove the SwipeItems of a SwipeControl in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use Microsofts new `SwipeControl` to allows users to reveal an action that's available to the item. What I'm struggling with is removing the `SwipeItems` when the action is no longer available, I know it is possible as setting and nulling the `LeftItems` property on the `SwipeControl` works as I expect it to, but I need it to be more dynamic than this.

Some notes on setup, I'm using Caliburn Micro as the MVVM framework and its implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm not using x:Bind.

Attempt 1 - Control based on `SwipeControl`:
I tried creating a new control based on the `SwipeControl`. I added DepedencyProps for `LeftItemsEnabled` and `InternalLeftItems`. InternalLeftItems is used to store the list of Items between each removal and reset. To remove and reset the `LeftItems` property I use the `LeftItemsEnabled` property by changing the boolean. I set the `LeftItems` to my `InternalLeftItems` value or to `null`. See below for code:

Dependency Properties and PropertyChanged implementation

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableLeftItemsProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("EnableLeftItems", typeof(bool), typeof(UpdatedSwipeControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, LeftEnabledPropertyChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalLeftItemsProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("InternalLeftItems", typeof(SwipeItems), typeof(UpdatedSwipeControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SwipeItems()));

public SwipeItems InternalLeftItems {
  get { return (SwipeItems)GetValue(InternalLeftItemsProperty); }
  set { SetValue(InternalLeftItemsProperty, value); }
}

private static void LeftEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  var control = d as UpdatedSwipeControl;
  if (control == null) return;

  control.EnableLeftItems = (bool)e.NewValue;
  if ((bool)e.NewValue)
      control.RightItems = control.InternalRightItems;
    else 
      control.RightItems = null;

    UpdateLayout();
}
```

Usage in View

```
<Page.Resources>
  <SymbolIconSource x:Key="ButtonIconSource"
                    Symbol="Cancel" />
  <SwipeItems x:Key="Items">
     <SwipeItem Text="SWIPE ITEM"
                IconSource="{StaticResource ButtonIconSource}"
                Background="Red" />
  </SwipeItems>
</Page.Resources>

<controls:UpdatedSwipeControl x:Name="swipeControl"
                              EnableLeftItems={Binding ItemsEnabled}
                              InternalLeftItems="{StaticResource Items}">
  <TextBlock Text="SWIPE" />
</SwipeControl>
```

Property in ViewModel

```
private bool itemsEnabled;
public bool ItemsEnabled {
  get {
    return itemsEnabled;
  }
  set {
    itemsEnabled = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(ItemsEnabled));
  }
}
```

Problem with this attempt is the `LeftEnabledPropertyChanged` only fired once, when changing from the default value `False` to `True` on the initial bind. It doesn't fire again on any of the subsequent NotifyPropertyChanged's. I not sure if I've missed something in my setup of the DependencyProps or the PropertyChangedEvent.

Attempt 2 - Converter on LeftItems prop:
My second attempt was to use a `Converter` on the Binding of the `boolean`. I created a simple converter to return either SwipeItems in my resources or `null`. See below for code:

Converter code

```
public class ItemsConverter : IValueConverter {

  public SwipeItems items { get; set; }

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
    return (bool) value ? items : null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Implementation in view

```
<Page.Resources>
  <sampleApp:ItemsConverter x:Key="converter" items="{StaticResource Items}"/>
  <SwipeItems x:Key="Items">
     <SwipeItem Text="SWIPE ITEM"
                IconSource="{StaticResource ButtonIconSource}"
                Background="Red" />
  </SwipeItems>
</Page>

<SwipeControl x:Name="swipeControl"
              LeftItems="{Binding ItemsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
  <TextBlock Text="SWIPE" />
</SwipeControl>
```

Same implementation of the ItemsEnabled Property on the ViewModel.
The problem with this attempt was the converter was never hit and there were no Binding errors.

In summation I know it's possible to set/reset the `SwipeItems` property via code-behind which works ok in very simple scenarios. But anything more dynamic I can't get to work. Has anyone else run into this issue or have a workaround to this?

Comment: Well this is awkward, after leaving it a few days and recompiling, Attempt 2 using the converter works as expected. I have no idea why it wouldn't work before. Not sure what to do with this question though, should I leave it for others in case they are trying the same thing?

Comment: SwipeControl only wroks in touch device, which device that you have tested with?

Comment: I've tested with a Surface Pro 3. After my recompile this morning it's working using the converter way. More wondering whether I should keep this question around for others to see or just delete it.

Comment: Your code looks correct, may compile issue cause this, you could delete this case.